# Как ускорить загрузку сайта https://ilikesushi.in.ua?

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart

Как ускорить загрузку сайта https://ilikesushi.in.ua ? Сайт на опенкарте. Есть ли какие-то модули для того, чтоб ускорить загрузку и где смотреть , чтоб ускорить загрузку сайта. Может код определенный убрать или вставить?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте начать с малого, [pagespeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=RU) от google.